# Nginx reverse proxy - Docker containers

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to configure an nginx proxy on the host machine, and proxy the requests to two containers. Two containers are running on ports `8000, 9000` respectively. However the nginx is not routing the request.

I have created nginx config like this in conf.d:

```
server {
    server_name api1.example.com;
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
server {
    server_name api2.example.com;
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf is like this

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I have also added the ap1.example.com and api2.example.com to etc/hosts

If i access api1.example.com it has to route to container on port 8000, and api2.example.com has to route to container on port 9000.

Both of them routing to apache2 default page.

Comment: In a container, `localhost` means the container itself. You need to use the address of the containers instead in your `proxy_pass` statements.

Comment: nginx is configured on host machine, i can access the container using just the port right?  the ran the container with -p 8000:80 @HansKilian

Comment: What's the problem you're running into?  What URL are you trying to connect to, and what result does it produce?